# What are the differences between tradefed and vts-tradefed?

Tags: android, android-source, android-tradefederation

I was looking online for an example for how to write own VTS tests and run them by Tradefed and found this article: https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/tradefed/fundamentals/full_example . But then digging deeper I realised that there are actually different tradefed tools. One generic tradefed and another one vts-tradfed.

Trying to understand the differences.